# Row-wise sorting a batch of pytorch tensors by column value

Tags: python, pytorch

I would like to sort each row in a `bxmxn` pytorch tensor (where `b` represents the batch size) by the k-th column value in each row. So my input tensor is `bxmxn`, and my output tensor is also `bxmxn` with the rows of each `mxn` tensor rearranged based on the k-th column value.

For example, if my original tensor is:

```
a = torch.as_tensor([[[1, 3, 7, 6], [9, 0, 6, 2], [3, 0, 5, 8]], [[1, 0, 1, 0], [2, 1, 0, 3], [0, 0, 6, 1]]])
```

My sorted tensor should be:

```
sorted_dim = 1 # sort by rows, preserving each row
sorted_column = 2 # sort rows on value of 3rd column of each row
sorted_a = torch.as_tensor([[[3, 0, 5, 8], [9, 0, 6, 2], [1, 3, 7, 6]], [[2, 1, 0, 3], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 6, 1]]])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
a = torch.as_tensor([[[1, 3, 7, 6], [9, 0, 6, 2], [3, 0, 5, 8]], [[1, 0, 1, 0], [2, 1, 0, 3], [0, 0, 6, 1]]])

b=torch.argsort(a[:,:,2])
sorted_a=torch.stack([a[i,b[i],:] for i in range(a.shape[0])] )
sorted_a
```

output:

```
tensor([[[3, 0, 5, 8],
         [9, 0, 6, 2],
         [1, 3, 7, 6]],

        [[2, 1, 0, 3],
         [1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 6, 1]]])
```

Comment: This uses for loop, not fast.